# Getting error with creating AWS Elasticsearch domain - Error setting policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, policy

I'm trying to setup AWS Elasticsearch but I can't get past the policy settings.
This is the policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::999999999999:user/xxxxx"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "es:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:eu-central-1:99999999999:domain/xyzdomain/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

this is the error:

```
CreateElasticsearchDomain: {"message":"Error setting policy: [{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"AWS\":[\"arn:aws:iam::9999999999:user/xxxxx\"]},\"Action\":[\"es:*\"],\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:es:eu-central-1:9999999999:domain/xyzdomain/*\"}]}]“}
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Setting it up how? There is an extra `“` character in the error message that looks odd.

Comment: Does your iam user in the policy actually exist?

Comment: The problem was the missing user. Thank you!

Comment: That's interesting. Most other places don't care if the user in the policy exists or not.